# Syntax Error in Postgresql Trigger Function

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm brand new. The task was to create a trigger that will delete all dependent tuples from the depositor table when an account in a parent table is deleted. Here's what I've got so far. I keep getting a syntax error "at or near 'cust_id'" and I can't find it. Can you tell me if this trigger will do what I'm wanting it to do (delete the cust_id and account_number from the depositor table for the account that was deleted in the account table) and help me find the syntax error?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Froehle_13_bankTriggerFunction()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
    BEGIN
        DELETE cust_id, account_number
        FROM depositor
        WHERE depositor.account_number = account.account_number;
    END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 3 changes:

1. Fix the `delete` statement syntax error by removing the columns. It must be just `delete from table where ...`
2. Replace `account` with the special keyword `old`, which refers to the row being deleted
3. Add a `return` statement, which is required for all trigger functions

Try this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Froehle_13_bankTriggerFunction()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM depositor
        WHERE depositor.account_number = OLD.account_number;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$$;
```

---

There is a final simplification you can make: Delete the entire function and instead alter the references constraint on the account_number column of depositor to add `ON DELETE CASCADE`.